# Dim UIButton text when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am using custom `UIButton`s, and what I want to do is make it so that when a user touches the button it dims, or turns a grayish color, like the regular button does.

I just want the text to temporarily change color temporally when the users lifts there figure it will be back to the regular color.

I have tried this code:

```
button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = TRUE;
```

but that just makes a white circle around it which is not what I'm looking for.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: For custom buttons you need to handle that manually. Subclass UIButton and add animations in touchesBegan and tochesEnd / touchesCancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the following `UIControlEvents`:

- `UIControlEventTouchDown`
- `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`
- `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`

Assign target-action methods to them appropriately like so:

```
 //when touch initiated
 [myButton addTarget:self
              action:@selector(buttonTouchStartAct:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

 //on touch released outside button bounds
 [myButton addTarget:self
              action:@selector(buttonTouchEndAct:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

 //on touch released while still inside button bounds (most commonly used)
 [myButton addTarget:self
              action:@selector(buttonAct:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

---

```
-(void)buttonTouchStartAct:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

-(void)buttonTouchEndAct:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}

-(void)buttonAct:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //touch ended in this case too
    [self buttonTouchEndAct:sender];

    //...
    //your main button logic
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I've come across is:

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing alpha of title label on button click like this

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = sender;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
    {
        [button.titleLabel setAlpha:0.5];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [button.titleLabel setAlpha:1];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //when touch initiated
 [myButton addTarget:self
              action:@selector(buttonTouchStartAct:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

 //on touch released outside button bounds
 [myButton addTarget:self
              action:@selector(buttonTouchEndAct:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

 //on touch released while still inside button bounds (most commonly used)
 [myButton addTarget:self
              action:@selector(buttonAct:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then inside the method change the color of the button